# How to use Quicken Home Inventory on Linux (or Windows 7)

Tags: wine

I have Quicken Home Inventory Manager and it seems that is no longer supported by Intuit, i.e. it does not run on newer Windows versions (like Windows 7 64-bit for example). Since I also use Linux, I'd like to try to use it on Linux if possible. Of course, I could install another inventory program, but there is no option to export data from QHIM and I have over 2 thousand items in the database, so I really have to keep using this proprietary software.

I tried running it under Wine but it's very slow to the point when it's completely unusable. It was very slow on Windows as well when I got more than a couple of hundreds of items, but under Wine the screen flickers all the time and I really cannot use it. I'm looking for some way to either tweak Wine settings or find some way to export data from QHIM's database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Wine, but you could use [Attic Manager](http://www.guacosoft.com/attic). It can load Quicken IDB file directly, and you can then either export it to CSV or keep using Attic Manager (it fits my needs just fine) to keep track of your inventory.

It is a native Linux application.

Comment: That's great. Do you know any other program with same capability? Possibly open source?

Comment: As far as I know, Attic Manager is the only product (Windows or Linux) that is able to load QHIM databases directly.

Comment: I just downloaded and tried the demo version. It loaded the IDB database file in seconds, cool. :) And it looks like it can store item pictures as well. Seems like exactly what I need. Thanks.